# ELF file generated in armv7, .o files in armv6, while using -march=armv6, why?

Tags: gcc, arm, g++, cross-compiling, armv6

I'm trying to compile my program to armv6, but the ELF file is built for armv7, even when I use `-march=armv6` option. All `.o` files has been compiled to armv6, only the ELF file is wrong.

Basically I'm compiling like this:

`arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -static -march=armv6 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -marm -Wa,-march=armv6 -o "Bridge"`

Checking all `.o` files I get this:

`$ readelf -a -W Bridge.o | grep Tag
  Tag_CPU_name: "6"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v6
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv2
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Aggressive Speed
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6`

But checking the ELF file:

`$ readelf -a -W Bridge | grep Tag
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3
  Tag_Advanced_SIMD_arch: NEONv1
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_rounding: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_VFP_args: VFP registers
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6`

I'm using Linaro GCC 7.2.1, and I've also tried with old versions, and different compilation flags combinations. Can someone tell me how to compile an armv6 ELF file?

Comment: the compiler calls the linker and perhaps you need to send explicit linker commands.  and/or link separately using the linker not the compiler.  you can also do some things to see what is being passed to the linker.  I would try using the linker directly first and specifying the architecture, before trying to get the compiler to send the right flags to the linker.

Comment: Im not seeing that though, yet.  I have a self built from sources 8.x.x and it defaults to architecture 4T unless otherwise specified, and when I specify armv6 on the compiler and let it call the linker, I get armv6.  On an arm based system using gcc directly not cross compiled it defaults to armv7 but when I specify armv6 on the command line and allow the compiler to call the linker I get armv6 in the final binary.

Answer (score 2):

Problem identified.
The Linaro toolchain binary was able to compile the object files for the armv6 platform, however, the linker actually did not interpret this flag.

Reason: the toolchain was compiled with the armv7 configuration.

Solution: I downloaded the source code for the Linaro toolchain, configured it to support armv6 and compiled it using the cross-ng-tool.